# Uso apropiado de la etiqueta soporte

Tags: discusión

He observado que algunas etiquetas no se están usando apropiadamente, obviamente<sup>1</sup>, desde mi punto de vista.

- ¿Cuál es el punto de vista oficial del uso de la etiqueta [soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte) ?

  - Pregunta relacionada en el sitio en inglés [What does "support" (like in the "support" required tag in Meta) means on the SE network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291269/)  publicada por mi mismo hace un rato.
  - Me parece que la etiqueta [soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte) debería usarse para asuntos de una sóla ocasión, que requieran la intervención de una persona con mayores privilegios que el autor de la pregunta. Esto porque preguntar acerca de las características de este sitio y la forma en que trabaja las considero "normales" por ser un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, **no un foro**, y la intención es que sea la propia comunidad que las responda, y sólo por excepción por personas contratadas como agentes de soporte técnico y/o desarrolladores. Para la atención por empleados de la empresa a cargo de los sitios de la red SE, está el enlace **contacto**, al pie de las páginas del mismo.

Comment: Ah veo, que lo comentas aquí, pero comenté en [otro sitio](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas#comment3900_427). Cada pregunta debe tener al menos una de las cuatro etiquetas: [bug], [soporte], [discusión] o [característica-nueva]. Eso no creo que exima a las que llevan "faq", por lo que lo más razonable parece que sea que lleven [soporte].

Comment: Por cierto, a mí al menos me resulta algo costoso leer estas preguntas con tantos bloques: referencias, notas, resumen... Creo que sería útil que abrazaras más el estilo markdown para los enlaces, así como utilizar de una forma más sucinta el espacio, más que nada porque es como la mayoría de la comunidad redacta y resulta más entendible. De la misma forma que eliminamos saludos y agradecimientos con la finalidad de dejar lo estrictamente necesario, creo que tus buenas preguntas también ganarían en comprensión si fueran más directas. ¡Gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: (¡No voté -1 por cierto! Creo que es un debate sano) Sigo por aquí para tenerlo todo junto. A ver, la definición de la etiqueta es _Solicitud de asistencia con alguna de las características del sitio_. Nunca lo había pensado de la manera que tú comentas, pues siempre me pareció obvio que se refiere a preguntas del tipo ¿cómo funciona esto? ¿qué pasa si hago aquello? Es decir, indicaciones de cómo funciona el sitio basadas en la documentación oficial.

Comment: Gracias a tí por tu tiempo @fedorqui. Pensando en la gente ocupada y los que no pueden o no quieren leer textos de más de 5 líneas es que empecé mi publicación con un resumen. En cuanto a hacer las cosas como la mayoría, en particular hacerlo así todo el tiempo, además de aburrido, me parece que inhibe oportunidades valiosas :)

Comment: Jaja _touché_, en lo de que no hace falta hacer las cosas como la mayoría te doy la razón :)

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Pues que bien que lo aclaras! Ya iba yo a arrancar una serie de votos negativos en TODAS tus publicaciones :D (por si caso, aclaro que lo dicho en este comentario es broma, no por tí, sino por algún lector peregrino que lea sólo una parte) .P.D. Voy por un café.

Comment: No sé si existe un uso inapropiado de esta etiqueta. En el caso de diferenciar entre `soporte`, `discusión` y `error` también lo veo factible que el OP para indicar en forma clara que es el contexto de su pregunta. En ausencia de `discusión` por ejemplo espera una respuesta concreta y concisa. a contrario `soporte` implica que necesita ayuda en algo que no pudo solucionar basado en la documentación encontrado.

Answer (score 1):

En la pregunta, mencioné que había publicado una pregunta similar en el sitio en inglés. Pues dicha pregunta ya tiene una respuesta que me parece apropiada. Por otro lado los comentarios a la pregunta así como otras publicaciones relacionadas que he encontrado en meta me llevan a la siguientes conclusiones:

[soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte) Es para publicaciones sobre preguntas y problemas acerca del funcionamiento del sitio principal o meta sitio correspondiente.

[discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n) Es para publicaciones en las que se declara una posición o propuesta con respecto al funcionamiento del sitio, ya sean características técnicas, políticas o prácticas, o bien, para realizar anuncios o consultas a la comunidad.

Cabe destacar que ambos tipos de publicaciones sólo se permiten en los meta sitio, no en los sitios principales.